# Error excluding transitive dependencies in Gradle build file

Tags: gradle

I have to exlude some dependencies from all modules of a multi module project.
With Gradle 1.12 the following gradle build file worked:

```
subprojects {
    ...
    //blacklisted dependencies
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'ojdbc14' //we use ojdbc6
        all*.exclude group: 'c3p0', module: 'c3p0' //newer versions use groupId: com.mchange
        all*.exclude module: 'oracledb' //we use ojdbc6
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

After upgrading to gradle version 2.1 i got error:

> You can't change configuration 'providedCompileScope' because it is
>   already resolved!

How to define exclusions now with the newer Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusions are still specified in the same way. Gradle is just telling you about a problem with your build that it wasn't telling you about before, namely that exclusions can only be declared before a configuration gets resolved. Probably there is some custom code that iterates over `configurations.providedCompileScope` (or a derived configuration) and mistakenly does so in the configuration phase (i.e. during evaluation of the build scripts), rather than in the execution phase (e.g. inside a task action). This snippet (and the resulting `--stacktrace`) may help to locate the problematic code:

```
configurations.providedCompileScope.incoming.beforeResolve { 
    println new Exception("resolved here") 
}
```

EDIT: If you have something like the following in one of your build scripts:

```
idea.module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.providedCompileScope
}
```

Change it to:

```
idea.module {
    scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.providedCompileScope]
}
```

This is necessary due to a change of behavior in the Groovy version used by Gradle 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I'd exclude transitive dependencies by specifying

```
dependencies {
    myConfiguration('group:module:version') { transitive = false }
}
```

For more fine grained control over versions etc, have a look at [ResolutionStrategy](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)